# Do racist/xenophobic Buddhists (attempt to) base their prejudice in religious doctrine?

Tags: religion, racism

Do the various racist or xenophobic movements in countries with Buddhist majorities (mainly in South East Asia) usually claim to base their prejudice (against other religions or ethnic groups) on Buddhist religious texts or some other kind of Buddhist religious doctrine?

A quick search finds that Buddhist monks are [sometimes involved](http://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,2146000,00.html) in such movements. It's not terribly clear if they claim to have some Buddhist religious doctrine backing them up.

Comment: I don't know, but given that it's de rigeur for bigoted people from other religions, I guess I'd be surprised if they didn't.

Comment: Anecdotal, but if you go to Buddhist conferences in Europe you'll quickly run into some rather disturbing [anti-muslim rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_Nydahl#Political_views). Also, there's more than one branch of Buddhism.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy: Isn't that rather like saying that if you went to a Jewish conference, you might hear a bit of anti-Nazi rhetoric?  Nor do I see what's particularly disturbing about the quote at your link.  Would you care to argue that Islam is NOT "...antithetical to freedom of speech and women's rights"?

Comment: @jamesqf: I've had the unpleasant experience of having been dragged into one of Olé's talks, and later met him face to face. The quotes on wikipedia are surface level stuff. There was a lot to dislike about Olés lengthy rants on Islam, and if they don't qualify as instilling prejudice in crowds then I don't know what does.

Comment: Isn't it a bit loaded question? I mean contemporary western discourse is secular and obsessed with issues of racism / xenophobia. If it is used as reference point then practically everything (including western past itself) is "shockingly" full of xenophobia and religious justified ideologies.

Comment: @Shadow1024: I'm mostly interested in contemporary Theravada-based movements, if that's not obvious enough from the question. I don't care much how they were 500 years ago, unless they invoke that past to justify present attitudes/actions.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy: Without being able to read those "lenghty rants" for myself, I can't judge.  All I can say is that what I see at your link seems to be reasonable & unbiased description of Islam. As far as instilling prejudice, I don't have any problem with being prejudiced against any group that is antithetical to freedom of speech and women's rights.

Comment: @jamesqf: In my view there's a not too subtle difference between being "prejudiced against" a group whose values are antithetical to your, and being committed to pushing them to change their views. I'm not disagreeing that it's a tough sale in this case, but shutting down on that idea completely from the get go doesn't strike me as very constructive. Anyway, let's leave it at that.

Comment: @jamesqf - What Ole is saying hardly qualifies as unbiased, unless you yourself see Islam as negative. Which seemingly is the case.

Comment: If someone said that Jesus was a terrible god, that "Islam and Judaism are fine, but I warn against Christianity," and that they were afraid of losing their freedom of speech because of  "some gentleman from the US who likes to beat their wives or stone them or whatever they do," I think it would be safe to call them prejudiced.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: As I said, can anyone reasonably argue that Islam is NOT against freedom of speech, given (for just a few examples of a great many) Charlie Hebdo, or blasphemy prosecutions and lynchings in Muslim-majority countries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_blasphemy?  Can anyone argue that it is not antithetical to women's rights, when women's rights activists are shot & jailed? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malala_Yousafzai https://www.npr.org/2019/05/22/725679176/won-t-give-up-siblings-of-jailed-saudi-women-s-rights-activist-speak-out-in-u-s

Comment: @Obie 2.0: If someone said that Jesus was a terrible god, I'd agree with them.  (With reservations about Jesus actually being a god, of course :-))  Even more so if they said Yahweh is a terrible god, or that Christianity has historically been and to some extent continues to be responsible for egregious human rights abuses.  Accepting objective evidence is not bias: refusing to accept such evidence is just being biased in the other direction.

Comment: @jamesqf - I don't think my point was that being anti-Christian on top of anti-Muslim would be an improvement.

Comment: @Obie 2.0: No, I think your point was that for some reason you refuse to look at these things objectively.